# Asp.NET MVC/Web API's pattern meet SignalR/Websockets

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

We have a Web Application that wants to make use of SignalR/Websockets in Asp.NET MVC. I am having difficulty understanding where the SignalR and/or Websockets end up in the directory structure that most the make sense and keeps to the separation of concerns (since SignalR/Websocket functions are technically like controllers).

So, is this more correct?

- Controllers
- Model
- Views
- Roles

Or is this more correct?

- Controllers

  - Roles (subfolder)
- Views
- Model

Second question: does it make sense to name it "Roles"?  Or is this a case of where we call the Folder SignalR?

The reason why I ask is that there has been a lot of emphasis on directory structure of MVC applications, (Models, Views, etc), but there does not seem to be much direction on where to put the Roles classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using SignalR 2 and you will use the `Hubs` the best way to manage es using:

- Models
- Views
- Controllers
- **Hubs**

In the Hubs folder you should create all the elements related to Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs like this:

```
namespace MyApp.Hubs
{
     using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

     public class MyHub : Hub
     {
     }
}
```

you can see a sample here:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/real-time-web-applications-with-signalr